# geodjango using mysql

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have been working on an application using django and mysql, am trying now to work on the tutorial from this here

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

but it failed the moment I ran syncdb with the following error

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

When I read around, it says that this can be solved if changed the backend to use postGIS. Is there a way to continue using mysql as my backend and yet be able to use geodjango? if not, is it possible to use both in the same project?

Regards,

Comment: The [GeoDjango installation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/#ref-gis-install) go into detail about what libraries are needed to use the various db backends.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

set `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql` in your settings.DATABASE engine db config.

Comment: "The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes"

Comment: where exactly do you put this?

Answer (score 5):

Does your MySQL have spatial data types installed? What do you get if you do:

```
CREATE TABLE geom (g GEOMETRY);
```

If that doesn't recognise the GEOMETRY type, then you need to upgrade/recompile/reconfigure your MySQL.

Comment: I tried it and it worked, the table was created. Anything from django setup I must do?

Comment: I found the problem, I was suppose to update the settings.py with the new mysql gis driver 'django.db.backends.mysql'. Now its working :)